# Select / combo popup break out of overflow scroll element

Tags: css

We have a select/combobox component and its popup picker menu cannot break out of a parent `<div style="overflow: scroll; height: 100px">` element. So essentially, the picker menu is hidden especially if the combobox is located near the top or bottom of the form.

I believe the reason is because the component uses relative positioning so that the picker can be the same size as the input:

```
    .combo {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 50;
    }
    .combo_wrapper {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: red;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
        max-height: 120px;
        z-index: 50;
    }
```

For example, in the image below, the red picker should extend outside of the blue scrolling element.

[image: Red popup should appear outside blue container]
Here's a simplified demo of the issue:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EqaMbK

If I comment out the `position: relative` CSS rule, then the red popup breaks out of the parent scrolling div, however the picker width then becomes the full page width.

I can solve the problem using JavaScript by setting the picker's minimum width to the combo's width:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QewoBR

But I was wondering if there's a pure CSS solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: visible;` to the parent, it will archived what you want while not break others css rules:

```
.scroll-panel {
   overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: Then the scroll-panel will not scroll.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `overflow: auto;` from `.scroll-panel` and replace it with `position: relative;` it will not be contained to the parent element but still be positioned relative to it.

Comment: You dont need `position: relative`, the `combo_list` is already related to `combo`, and since the default-value of `overflow` is `visible`, that make it show up

Comment: I may not have been clear in my question. The scroll-panel is not part of the combobox markup. The combobox may be one of several components contained within a scroll-panel. The behavior of the scroll-panel, if its not obvious, is to show scrollbars if content overflows its bounds.